# #include <ranges>, but no namespace 'ranges' found

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, c++20

I want to use `std::ranges:views::filter`, but VS2019 failed to find `std::ranges` even `#include <ranges>`.  I'll show you this problem with test project.

I've created 'Console App' project on Visual Studio 2019 community, and set up `C++ Language Standard` to `ISO C++20 Standard (/std:c++20)`.

Now the problem : if I type `#include <ranges>` & `std::ranges;`, an error comes out : `error C2039: 'ranges': is not a member of 'std'`. How do I get VS2019 to include ranges correctly?

[image]

Comment: VS2019 did not support C++20 ranges before its version 16.10, which was released late May 2021.   If you're using a version predating May 2021  (16.9 and earlier) it may support some subset of (then in draft/proposed) C++20 but won't support ranges.

Comment: Oh after updating to 16.11.15 then it works! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> C++20 Standard Library features are available in Visual Studio 2022
> version 17.2 and Visual Studio 2019 version 16.11.14. [devblog
> link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/msvcs-stl-completes-stdc20/)

I update Visual Studio 2019 from 16.11.9 to 16.11.15, then `<ranges>` works.

Comment: I can confirm that 16.11.13 is not sufficient.